# Multiple divs with similar background image names

Tags: css, sass

Hay I want to simplify this sass code

```
.btn1
   background-image: url(../images/other-services-1.jpg)

.btn2
   background-image: url(../images/other-services-2.jpg)

.btn3
   background-image: url(../images/other-services-3.jpg)

.btn4
   background-image: url(../images/other-services-4.jpg)

.btn5
   background-image: url(../images/other-services-5.jpg)

.btn6
   background-image: url(../images/other-services-6.jpg)

.btn7
   background-image: url(../images/other-services-7.jpg)

.btn8
   background-image: url(../images/other-services-8.jpg)
```

It seems like there should be an alternative
that should be easier and quicker to apply
but i can't think of one

Any Suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tested and will work:

```
@for $i from 1 through 8
  .btn#{$i}
    background-image: url(../images/other-services-#{$i}.jpg)
```

Tested on: http://www.sassmeister.com/ (make sure you have the site set to **SASS** and **NOT SCSS**)

Produces this css:

```
.btn1 {
  background-image: url(../images/other-services-1.jpg);
}

.btn2 {
  background-image: url(../images/other-services-2.jpg);
}

.btn3 {
  background-image: url(../images/other-services-3.jpg);
}

.btn4 {
  background-image: url(../images/other-services-4.jpg);
}

.btn5 {
  background-image: url(../images/other-services-5.jpg);
}

.btn6 {
  background-image: url(../images/other-services-6.jpg);
}

.btn7 {
  background-image: url(../images/other-services-7.jpg);
}

.btn8 {
  background-image: url(../images/other-services-8.jpg);
}
```

Comment: Darren Sweeney *Slow clap* you are a genius :) thank you so much for your help.

Comment: No worries, please accept the answer when you can - thanks

Comment: how do i do this, haven't does this before

Comment: @RichardDeanShaunPotgieter Click the tick mark on the left of the answer

Comment: awesome you deserve it

Answer (score 0):

This (untested!) code should do the trick:

```
@for $i from 1 through 8
  .btn#{$i}
   background-image: url(../images/other-services-#{$i}.jpg)
```

Comment: OK thanks, I did say untested and your answer is, somewhat, similar. Maybe a comment on my answer so I could edit it would have been nice? :)

Comment: I didn't see your answer until I posted mine tbh, I was testing it ha ha - anyway, for future ref, to replace a wrong answer by correcting it to be the same as a correct answer might be frowned upon on SO!

Comment: I added a hash, and credited you in the edit. I figured you'd seen my answer, and (slightly) corrected it. If in fact, as you say, you answered it independently, my apologies.

Comment: i went on http://www.sassmeister.com/ and this is the error code i get on this css side - Invalid CSS after "...rom 1 through 8": expected "{", was ".btn#{$i}" , thanks for the help so far :)

Comment: Both wrong after all that haha, come on, an upvote for each? haha

Comment: wish we could figure it out though :( i could benefit a lot from this

Comment: I am sure its very close, I assume it's just a syntax tweak